# Is electronvolt a mass or an energy unit?

Tags: units, mass-energy

I always thought electronvolt was an unit of energy and I knew its definition, but in these days I got some doubts because I saw 2 times it was used as an unit of mass: in my school textbook, in an article about the 4 fundamental forces, it was used as a mass unit; and in a famous magazine I read the same thing (same arguments)

> In physics, the electron volt (symbol eV; also written electronvolt[1][2]) is a unit of energy equal to...

particularly there was a table about sub-atomic particles with .... spin | charge | **mass(GeV)** | ...

Comment: See ["Electronvolt: Mass"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronvolt#Mass).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Strictly speaking it's a unit of energy. But using $m=\frac{E}{c^2}$, you can convert energy into mass.
Operating, we get $1{\rm\,eV}/c^2 =1.78\cdot 10^{-36}\rm{\,kg}$. (The $c^2$ is usually ommited.)

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely a unit of energy, though your confusion may arise due to the usage of what's known as [geometrized units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrized_unit_system), where c the speed of light (in addition to the gravitational constant G) is set to unity. This is typically done in [General Relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity). In this system, mass and energy have exactly the same units - they are two sides of the same coin.

Answer (score 1):

It is an energy unit, however you can use it as a mass unit too because of the famous Einstein relation E=m*c^2. If you are given a mass in eV, you just have to use that formula to get the corresponding mass in real mass units.